# How to create grid view layout with HTML & CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have create Grid layout with responsive like bellow:

[image]

but I don't want to apply space after second rows. I want to style like pintrest.

Exactly what I want is:

[image]

My Sample : [HTML](http://goo.gl/24W6BJ)

I will appropriate If someone help to complete this view :)

Thanks

Comment: use http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: +1 for [masonry.desandro.com](http://masonry.desandro.com).

Comment: `CSS3 columns`?  - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-columns/  here's a list of browser support for columns - http://caniuse.com/#search=columns

Comment: @Adsy Hi. I don't want to use jQuery. Any other way to fix in this html.

Comment: @NickR I have created this html but still I am not good with html :D

Comment: @user3113858 if you only want html, The easiest way I could suggest would be to create a three column table with fixed width and align:top and nest tables inside each column.

Comment: Something like - http://jsfiddle.net/LJY9B/2/

Comment: @NickR Yes I want like this but having some issue with layout and responsive is not working like mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using bootstrap

for e.g.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
</div>
```

add as many as div you want. They will grow horizontally as per content and then will be floated left.

Comment: there are some other frameworks available with different advantages such as Foundation, Boilerplate etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your layout..
We have create demo content for your layout..

Click on following link and download source code: http://www.chameleoninfotech.com/theme/mansory-layout/mansory-layout.zip

I hope its helpful for you..

Answer (score -1):

Does something like this work for you? basically what I explained in the comments:

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VLPX9/)

I've used `table-layout:fixed` to keep the width from messing up.

You'd just need to adjust the width of the columns to suit your content

Comment: Thanks for your great response and help but I am using responsive layout and don't want to use table.

Comment: Not a problem, sorry I couldn't help but I don't think what you're after is possible with just HTML.

Comment: It's Okay and Thanks for supporting me :)